# Python external_dependencies: 'google-cloud-pubsub' not working

Tags: python, odoo, google-cloud-pubsub

Environment details
Google cloud pubsub
window 10
Python version: 3.6.3
google-cloud-pubsub version: 0.39.1
Steps to reproduce
I used google-cloud-pubsub in Odoo module. I tried to explain the issue in step by step.

Added 'google-cloud-pubsub' in external_dependencies in python manifest file:

```
"external_dependencies": { 'python': ['google-cloud-pubsub'] },
```

Expected result:
 Actually, I don't know why this error occurs. Normally it will be work.

Actual result:
When I published python module to Odoo server its threw below error:

```
odoo.exceptions.UserError: ('Unable to install module "caliva_wsp" because an 
   external dependency is not met: No module named google-cloud-pubsub', '')
```

How to solve this issue? I already stuck at this point around 3 days.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message is the expected result if you have not installed the dependency. Odoo module manifest external dependencies only check that the external module is available from Odoo code. It does not install the module.

Install google pubsub pip module on your Odoo server with command `pip3 install google-cloud-pubsub` before installing your own Odoo module. After that your module should be installable.

You can also automate the installation of dependency by putting it in module requirements.txt file. More information on this can be found at https://www.odoo.com/documentation/user/12.0/odoo_sh/getting_started/first_module.html#use-an-external-python-library.

Comment: I user Ooo.sh for enterprise version.When I run command pip3 install google-cloud-pubsub,Its installed some dependencies but end of the line show below error:

"Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/protobuf-3.6.1-py3.5-nspkg.pth'"

Also when I run command with use of sudo then its show below error:
sudo: /usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set

Comment: Have you tried the Odoo module requirements.txt (https://www.odoo.com/documentation/user/12.0/odoo_sh/getting_started/first_module.html#use-an-external-python-library) or odoo.sh site FAQ (https://www.odoo.sh/faq) item "Can I install dependencies packages?". I assume your issue is because odoo.sh users do not have full access in the container.

Comment: odoo.sh/faq is the perfect answer. actually, my mistake was that I added the requirements.txt file at module root but it's the not correct way. 
Add requirements.txt file to repo root directory then it works fine.
Thank you for help